# Text-Indent vs Position for SEO

Tags: css, text, seo, position, indentation

What's the best way to hide a text element and replace it with an image while still maintaining good SEO. I've seen negative text-indent, but I prefer absolute positioning with negative top.

So what I'd like to know is which is better for SEO. Do most search engines consider text elements with negative top with absolute positioning; likewise for text-indent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would be very surprised if there was any difference. Search engines care about your content, they don't generally download your stylesheets, so all they would see is the markup which would be the same for both methods.

Image replacement is good for users and search engines, so as long as you're not doing it for the purpose of cloaking, you'll be fine.

Comment: Yes, these are my thoughts exactly.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid the accepted answer isn't the case as far as actual communications from Google indicate (as frustrating as that is!). Take a look here:

http://luigimontanez.com/2010/stop-using-text-indent-css-trick/

and here:

http://maileohye.com/html-text-indent-not-messing-up-your-rankings/

The answers indicates that any CSS that seems to hide content from the user could be considered bad, simply because the techniques have been tainted by their use by black-hat SEOs. Though they are super handy for development (and kind of required when using CSS sprites effectively), it looks like there isn't a Google accepted best practise to address this. Yet....

Comment: Interesting. I wonder what is to stop spammers from using the alt attribute for blackhat SEO.

Comment: Good point. I suppose the issue is slightly different: using text-indent to push text off the screen is physically hiding something, whilst the alt attribute is hidden as standard. No doubt Google carefully scrutinise the alt attributes use as well to make sure it isn't being exploited.

Comment: I found this answer helpful: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/11216/23096, which led me to these very helpful links:
http://css-tricks.com/css-image-replacement/ and
http://css-tricks.com/examples/ImageReplacement/